# is this a shorthand for distributive property?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My math teacher was showing me this as a step using substitution to solve this system: $4y=5x-1$ and $3x-2y=1$. I now know the answer to this question but what confused me was when we reached this step: $4( {3x-1\over 2} ) = 5x-1$. I expected the distributive property to be used, but instead he used this: $\not4 ( {3x-1\over \not2} ) = 5x -1$. Are the crossed out numbers just shorthand for distributive property?
(I do not know how to get \not to work within the fraction.)

Comment: The $4$ should become a $2$ after the cancellation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$4y=5x-1.....(1)$$
$$3x-2y=1.....(2)$$
Find the value of $y$ from equation(2),

$y=(\dfrac{3x-1}{2})$

Put the value of $y$ in equation(1),

$$4(\dfrac{3x-1}{2})=5x-1$$

Now, divide 4 by 2

$$^2\not4(\dfrac{3x-1}{\not2})=5x-1$$

$$2(3x-1)=5x-1$$

$$6x-2=5x-1\;\;\implies 6x-5x=2-1\;\;\implies x=1$$

Now, put the value of $x$ in equation(2),
$$3(1)-2y=1$$
$$-2y=1-3\;\;\implies y=\dfrac{-2}{-2}=1$$
I hope it' ll help you.